# How can I put data from YouTube videos into an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python, excel, youtube

I am trying to get data from the first hundred or so results when searching for something on YouTube. I found a few strings of code that Google offered but I am having trouble executing them properly:

```
def SearchAndPrint(search_terms):
    yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
    query = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeVideoQuery()
    query.vq = search_terms
    query.orderby = 'viewCount'
    query.racy = 'include'
    feed = yt_service.YouTubeQuery(query)
    PrintVideoFeed(feed)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide more information: what "strings of code" are, what language, etc.

Comment: ah! I'm sorry. I'm using Python. This is what I found:

def SearchAndPrint(search_terms):
  yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
  query = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeVideoQuery()
  query.vq = search_terms
  query.orderby = 'viewCount'
  query.racy = 'include'
  feed = yt_service.YouTubeQuery(query)
  PrintVideoFeed(feed)

Comment: @JeffMilnazik I edited your question to add the code; you can always update your question in response to comments. Simply click on the `edit` link.

Comment: ah thank you! I tried to do that but it wouldn't edit correctly.. thanks!

Comment: What specific problem are you having? You'll need to make sure that the `gdata` library is installed and that you've done the proper `import`s before running this code, but beyond that, it's hard to debug "having trouble executing them properly". Are you getting an error message? If so, post the full message and traceback. Not sure how to run the code in the first place? Then say so. :)

Comment: @Dougal I am way out of my league here.. my mistake. I was given this task and was recommended that Python would be a route to take to not make it take forever (getting data from hundreds of youtube videos by searching) so I decided to try it, with no prior experience. I have no idea what I'm doing. Thanks for the help! I'm going to take some time and really learn what this is about before trying these harder tasks. Thanks again all!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way you can achieve the goal you mentioned is to output the results to a Comma Separated Values (CSV) file. Excel is able to open CSV files.

```
def PrintVideoFeed(feed):
  print 'title,published,description,category,tags,URL'
  for entry in feed.entry:
    PrintEntryDetails(entry)

def PrintEntryDetails(entry):      
  print '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s' % (entry.media.title.text, entry.published.text, entry.media.description.text, entry.media.category[[]0].text, entry.media.keywords.text, entry.GetSwfUrl())
```

If the script is called 'SearchYouTube.py', the command line could be:

python SearchYouTube.py > results.csv